# how to resize specific gridline(s) in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I want to get a line width of 10 on specific points in the chart.

I can get a line width of 10 but on all lines with the **following code:**

```
gridLines: {
    display: true,
    lineWidth: 10
},
```

**Current chart:**

[image: My current chart]

Is it possible to add specific width on different gridlines

**What i want:**

[image: to achieve]

**Codepen:**
https://codepen.io/flowwdelapro/pen/RwPMbvb

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: @vadivela i've tried to add width that worked but for all but i want to know how i can specify the exact location of the lineWidth.

Comment: can you share demo?

Comment: @vadivela i added a demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an array instead of a number.

```
lineWidth: [1,1,10,1,10]
```

The number are applied from left to right.

Comment: Didn't even know that it was that simple just to use an array. Thanks a lot, worked for me!